# How do I reinstall KDE Plasma without doing a fresh install

Tags: kde, plasma-5

so I tried to customize my KDE desktop using Latte dock and some other tools, but then I didn’t like it because it started to break my desktop and a lot of bugs. So, how can I reinstall KDE Plasma without having to do a fresh installation of Kubuntu ? Thanks.

**Note :**

```
OS : Kubuntu 21.10
Plasma version : 5.22.5
KDE frameworks version : 5.86.0
Qt version : 5.15.2
```

I have also tried `rm .kde/share/config/kdeglobals` but nothing changes and I don't have **plasma-*** in `.kde/share/config/plasma-*`.

I also already removed **latte-dock** and **kvantum-manager**

Answer (score 3):

Open the *Terminal* and type `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` first.
Then reinstall *KDE Desktop* with the command `sudo apt install --reinstall kde-plasma-desktop`.
Remember that re-installing *plasma* will not help with any broken settings, as they are stored in your home folder and are not affected by reinstalling packages.
Also ***and some other tools*** is very vague. That makes answering your indirect question 'why is my KDE Plasma DE broken?' impossible. But you can start with this and let us know the outcome.
A trick you can apply is creating another user and see if the bug is still there.

Comment: **some other tools** means `kvantum-manager` and some Kubuntu plugins to change themes.